# Keytool get stuck in Instance created on openstack victoria

Tags: java, openstack, keytool, openstack-nova

I have installed openstack Victoria in bare metal, created a centos8.1 instance(4cpu,4gb ram,20gb hard disk), when I am running keytool command in instance it takes few hours to finish the command, same issue I am facing when running java command.(On openstack Rocky,we don't see this issue)

`/usr/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore1 -storetype PKCS12 -validity 10000 -storepass abcdefgh -dname "cn=xyz - self-signed, ou=abc, o=abc, c=US" -keypass abcdefgh`

we have used openjdk , oracle jdk 8 & 11

Comment: Perhaps the instance can't provide sufficient randomness to `keytool`. Is `haveged` installed on it?

Comment: @berndbausch I have tried it, its not helpful

Comment: `strace` to find out where it is spending time?